# Mobilefirst-8.0 JavaScript Adapter for SOAP service

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have created MobileFirstPlatform-v8.0 Javascript Adapter which invokes a SOAP web service. But  I am unable to get a response from my swagger tool and WLRequest invoke procedure also. Kindly assist me.

My project environment : Mfp 8.0 with IONIC2 and AngularJS2

currently my SOAP service running in local tomcat server.

code :

```
<connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>localhost</domain>
            <port>8080</port>
            <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
        </connectionPolicy>
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="getFeed" secured="false"/>
```

adapter-impl.js file

```
function getFeed(type) {

    MFP.Logger.error("----------------"+type);

    var request =
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:q0="http://jee.javapapers.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <soapenv:Body>
        <q0:animalType>
          <q0:animal>{type}</q0:animal>
        </q0:animalType>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>;
    MFP.Logger.error("-----request ----"+request);
    var input = {
        method: 'post',
        returnedContentType: 'xml',
        path: '/animalType.asmx',
        body: {
            content: request.toString(),
            contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        }
    };

    var result = MFP.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    return result.Envelope.Body;
};

invokeAdapter(){
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/HTTPSOAP/getFeed/",WLResourceRequest.POST);
    resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params", "['world']");
    resourceRequest.send().then((response) => {
    console.log("success"+JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    function(error){
       console.log("---failed--->"+JSON.stringify(error));
    });
  }
```

**Error mfp message logs:**

> FWLST0904E: Exception was thrown while invoking procedure: {0} in
>   adapter: {1} Http request failed: java.net.SocketException: Connection
>   reset

Thanks advance...

Comment: To aid debugging you could look at using a tool such as Wireshark to view the actual network packets and check what's happening there.

Comment: i am using my localhost and my backend sample SOAP service running in my tomcat server only.

Comment: "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" tells you that the backend - in this case your webservice on tomcat server has reset the connection.